# window.open() don't work in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a react application that looks like this: I have a button when it's clicked it will open a popup with a ticket to be printed, the click handler is passed from a parent component to the button and I want the same process to be done inside the parent component

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
  openWindow = id => {
    window.open('/service/ticket/' + id + '/print')
  }

  submitPayment = () => {
    sendPayment(this.state.rawCommand.id, updatedCommand.payment) 
      .then(payment => {
        if (payment.needed > 0) { 
          toastr.success(dictionnary.acceptedPayment)
        } else {
          toastr.success(dictionnary.payee) 
          this.openWindow(updatedCommand.id)
        } 
      }

  render () {
    <Printer printTicket={this.openWindow} />
  }
}
```

and

```
const Printer = ({printTicket, id}) => {
  const clickHandler = () => printTicket(id)

  return (
    <button onClick={clickHandler}>print</button>
  )
}
```

The problem is when the button in the Printer component is clicked the window is opened as expected, but when the openWindow click handler is invoked from the parent component nothing is happening!

I inspected the code in chrome devtools and the function is invoked but the popup does not open.

**Edit**
More explanation:
1- the button opens a popup with a ticket and print it
2- the user can print a ticket via this button
3- after submitting a payment the ticket should be printed automaticaly

Comment: I'd expect to see a ReferenceError for `commandId` on the console with that code.

Comment: it's a typo in the question only thank you!

Comment: How are you invoking `submitPayment`?

Comment: submitPayment is passed as props to another component and when it's invoked it does an ajax call which returns a Promise, and when the Promise is resolved it calls this.openWindow.

Comment: _'but when the openWindow click handler is invoked from the parent component nothing is happening'_, where is the code that invoked it within the parent and not a child component?

Comment: ```javascript
sendPayment(this.state.rawCommand.id, updatedCommand.payment)
      .then(payment => {
        if (payment.needed > 0) {
          toastr.success(dictionnary.acceptedPayment)
        } else {
          toastr.success(dictionnary.payee)
          this.openWindow(updatedCommand.id)
        }
        updatedCommand.payment = payment
        afterUpdateCommand(updatedCommand)
        sendToSocket(currUserId, 'update', updatedCommand.id, false, null)
      })
```

Comment: Please move that code to your question, and explain how it is connected to the rest of your code.

Comment: just a minute!!

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution it's about google chrome: it blocks the popup!!!